# Cómo puedo poner una imagen en html que ocupe todo el ancho de la pantalla y sea responsive

Tags: html, imagen, responsive

Estoy poniendo una imagen en mi web y quiero que me vaya de izquierda a derecha y ocupe toda la zona de la pantalla. Como se ve en la imagen solo aparece en un trozo y no sé que propiedades de css tengo que poner para que se ajuste de izquierda a derecha o si tengo que alargar los pixeles con algún programa. La imagen va justo debajo del header y encima del formulario. Adjunto código aunque la imagen no se verá. También tiene que ser responsive y se adapte a cualquier tipo de pantalla. Si me pudierais asesorar un poco. Muchas gracias.

```html
<html>
<style>
    .imagen {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .titulo {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;
        color: white;
    }

    .parrafo {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        color: white;
    }

</style>
<body>

    <div class="imagen">
        <img src="/WebBurger/public/img/fotoregistro.jpg" class="foto">
        <div class="titulo"><b>REGISTRARME</b></div>
        <div class="parrafo"><b>Regístrate para disfrutar de múltiples funcionalidades</b></div>
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <form action="../public/forms/registro.php" method="post">
            <dl>
                <dt><label for="nombre">NOMBRE</label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" maxlength="30" size="29" required /></dd>
                <dt><label for="apellidos">APELLIDOS</label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" maxlength="30" required /></dd>
                <dt><label for="fecha_nacimiento">FECHA DE NACIMIENTO</label></dt>
                <dd><input type="date" id="fecha_nacimiento" name="fecha_nacimiento" required /></dd>
                <dt><label for="telefono">TELÉFONO</label></dt>
                <dd><input type="tel" id="telefono" name="telefono" required placeholder="XXXXXXXXX" pattern="[0-9]{9}" /></dd>
                <dt><label for="ciudad">CIUDAD</label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" id="ciudad" name="ciudad" maxlength="50" required /></dd>
                <dt><label for="email">EMAIL</label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="usuario@direccion.com" required maxlength="30" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" /></dd>
                <p class="texto-contra">
                    La contraseña debe contener al menos un número, una mayúscula, una minúscula y un mínimo de 8 caracteres.
                </p>
                <dt><label for="contrasena">CONTRASEÑA</label></dt>
                <button id="mostrar_contrasenaregistro" type="button" onclick="mostrarContrasenaregistro()"> <span class="fa fa-eye-slash icon"></span> </button>
                <dd><input type="password" id="contrasena" name="contrasena" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" maxlength="40" required /></dd>
                <dd><input type="submit" name="usub" value="¡Quiero registrarme!" /></dd>
            </dl>

        </form>
        <?php include(__DIR__.'/../lib/inc/footer.php'); ?>
    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: "Como se ve" en cual imagen?  Agrega un código en el que podamos reproducir tu mismo error por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

con el atributo `width: 100%;` el objeto se ensancha al tamaño del padre, añadeselo a la imagen